# If $\mu,\nu$ are measures and $\mu \ge \nu$ and $\nu$ $\sigma$-finite then there exists $\lambda$ with $\mu$=$\nu+\lambda$ (Measure-Theory)

Tags: measure-theory

Let M be a $\sigma$-algebra over X and let $\mu$ and  $\nu$ be $\sigma$-additive functions.
Additionally let $\mu \ge\nu$ for all $E\in M$ and let $\nu$ be $\sigma$-finite.
Then there exists a $\sigma$-additive function $\lambda$ such that $\mu(E)=\nu(E)+\lambda(E)$.

I want to proof this, but I dont know how to do this. This is what I already have:

Defining $\lambda=\mu-\nu$ doesnt work, because you might end up with $\infty-\infty$.
However, for $\nu(E)<\infty$ this works so I only have to find $\lambda(E)$ for $\nu(E)=\infty$.

My first attempt was to simply set $\lambda(E)=\infty$ for $\nu(E)=\infty$. However, I am of the opinion that this is wrong since if $\lambda$ was $\sigma$-additive and $\bigcup_1^\infty A_i$ with $\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty A_i)=\infty$ and $\nu(A_i)<\infty$ you could compute

$$\lambda(\bigcup_1^\infty A_i)=\infty$$
and
$$\lambda(\bigcup_1^\infty A_i)=\sum_1^\infty\lambda(A_i)=\sum_1^\infty\mu(A_i)-\nu(A_i)$$
and for example if $\mu(A_i)-\nu(A_i)=\frac{1}{i^2}$ this would converge and be less than infinity what would be a contradiction to the assumption that $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-additive.

So does this case happen? And if so what is the propper way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are $\mu, \nu$ assumed to be positive? Is $\lambda$ required to be positive?

Comment: Maybe you can do something with the fact that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite so there exists events $A_1,\dots \in M$ s.d. $A_n \uparrow X$ and $\nu(A_n) < \infty$. I'm thinking of localizing $\lambda_n(E) := \mu(E \cap A_n) - \nu(E\cap A_n)$ and then take limit later. Just a thought, not an answer.

Comment: By the way, in MathJax it is better to write entire formulas in math mode, instead of just individual symbols.  I edited your post.

Comment: Yes, all functions are from M to [0,$\infty$]. I only know $\sigma$ additivity from this kind of functions, sorry for not stating it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...However, for $\nu(E)<\infty$ this works..."

Exploit this!

Let $(E_n)_n$ be a sequence of disjoint measurable sets with $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ and $\nu(E_n)<\infty$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

Prescribe $\mu_n$ on $M$ by $E\mapsto\mu(E\cap E_n)$ and $\nu_n$ by $E\mapsto\nu(E\cap E_n)$.

Then for a fixed $n\in\mathbb N$ for every $E\in M$  there is a unique $r\in[0,\infty]$ such that $\mu_n(E)=\nu_n(E)+r$ so we can prescribe $\lambda_n(E)$ in such a way that it satisfies $\mu_n(E)=\nu_n(E)+\lambda_n(E)$.

Finally prescribe $\lambda$ by $E\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n(E\cap E_n)$.

It remains to be proved that $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-additive.

Give that a try yourself. I would start with proving that the $\lambda_n$ are $\sigma$-additive.

Comment: Ok, I tried this
I plugged $\bigcup_1^\infty A_k$ into $\mu_n(E)=\nu(E)_n+r$ which gives $\sum_1^\infty \mu_n(A_k)=\sum_1^\infty \nu_n(A_k) + r$

For each $A_k$ we get a $r_k$ so we can write $r=\sum_1^\infty r_k$. Identifying r with $\lambda$ we get that $\lambda(\bigcup_1^\infty A_k)=\sum_1^\infty r_k = \sum_1^\infty \lambda_n(A_k)$ So this means $\lambda_n$ is $\sigma-additive$.

I kindof did the same:
$\mu(\bigcup_1^\infty A_k)=\nu(\bigcup_1^\infty A_k)+\lambda(\bigcup_1^\infty A_k) 
$<=>$
\sum_1^\infty \mu(A_k)=\sum_1^\infty \nu(A_k)+\sum_1^\infty \lambda_n(\bigcup_1^\infty A_k) $

Comment: And because $\lambda_n$ is $\sigma-additive$ we get:
$\sum_1^\infty \mu(A_k)=\sum_1^\infty \mu(A_k)+\sum_1^\infty \sum_1^\infty \lambda_n(A_k) <=> \sum_1^\infty \mu(A_k)=\sum_1^\infty \mu(A_k) + \sum_1^\infty \lambda(A_k)$
Sorry for making it a wall of text, I couldn't figure out how to begin a new line. I would really appreciate another reply.

Comment: If it has been shown that the $\lambda_n$ are $\sigma$-additive then you can prove the same for $\lambda$ by: $\lambda\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(E_{n}\cap A_{k}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}\left(E_{n}\cap A_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}\left(E_{n}\cap A_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}\left(A_{k}\right)$

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Is the proof for the $\sigma$-additivity of $\lambda_n$ I wrote right?

Comment: I haven't checked it, but we have: $\nu_{n}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)+\lambda_{n}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)=\mu_{n}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)$
and also: $\nu_{n}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}\left(A_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}v_{n}\left(A_{k}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}\left(A_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[v_{n}\left(A_{k}\right)+\lambda_{n}\left(A_{k}\right)\right]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu_{n}\left(A_{k}\right)=\mu_{n}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)$.

Comment: This together implies that $\lambda_{n}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}\left(A_{k}\right)$. Check yourself.

Comment: I think this is what I tried to do. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: You are very welcome. If my answer was useful enough then you can accept it.